# c++: polymorphism + multiple inheritance order. Is the inheritace order significant?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

I'm trying to solve a little mystery about the code similar to the following:

```
struct Interface {
    virtual void f () = 0;
}

struct SomeClass {
    virtual void additionalBehaviour () = 0;
    void g () {
        additionalBehavoiur ();
        /*Some stuff with printing into a ostringstream*/
    }
}

struct Derived : public SomeClass, public Interface {
    void additionalBehaviour () { /*Some printing to oss*/ }
    void f () { g (); }
}

int main () {
    unique_ptr<Interface> ifc (new Derived ());
    ifc->f ();
    cout << "HI!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It works, but quits randomly causing с0000005 0a9e appcrash on Windows having done the things listed in `g ()` partly *and* having printed "HI!".
So, at some point it stops printing into the file, finishes everything else and, finally, crashes. Some point means an indeed *some* point: for example, `file << "phrase"` may produce `phra` and nothing after that.
Also, it executes correctly and does not crash when executed in GDB. And there are no memory leaks according to Dr. Memory.

The solution:

```
struct Derived : public Interface, public SomeClass {
    void f () { g (); }
}
```

**The question:** why?!
I suppose it is something about the relative field positions in classes, but what about no crashing in GDB and no signs of memory problems then?

Comment: _"I'm trying to solve a little mystery about the code **similar to the following** "_ Do not post code which does not exhibit problematic behaviour. Make an [MCVE]. Judging from code you posted, you forgot to make the destructor virtual.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot The problem can perfectly be reproduced.  I get systematically a runtime error:  http://ideone.com/djvWKO

Comment: It's `SomeClass` and `Interface` missing a virtual destructor.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot yes, I forgot the destructors. But they are not called until the end of `main()`, so they should not spoil the `ostringstream` nor the `ofstream` interrupting the printing

Comment: @Alex, then please explain this working example:  http://ideone.com/LEhvIt  Compare that to Christophe's example, which is your code you have now.

Comment: As I stated, it prints "HI!": <<having done the things listed in g () partly *and* having printed "HI!".>>

Comment: _"they should not spoil "_ It is UB. Anything can happen. Compiler just reordered some things to happen after destruction. It can do that if it does not change visible behavious of **well-formed** program That everything seems to work if `Interface` is first in inheritance list, supports missing virtual destructor reason.

Comment: @Alex  A derived class is being deleted using a base class pointer behind the scenes.  When that happens, you better have your base class to have a virtual destructor.  If not, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot well, the destructors seem to solve everything. Thanks for the remark about optimization, it was quite unobvious

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the problem is related to the fact that you have no virtual destructor.  This is why the processing in g() is performed:  the crash happens when unique_ptr to destroy the object.

Like this it should work:

```
struct Interface {
    virtual void f () = 0;
    virtual ~Interface() {};
};
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/djvWKO)

***Standard reference:***

> **5.3.5/3:** In the first alternative (delete object), if the static type of the object to be deleted is different from its dynamic type,
>   the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the
>   object to be deleted **and the static type shall have a virtual
>   destructor** or the behavior is undefined.